# Read first N bytes of a url in scala?

Tags: java, scala, http, streaming

I have a url that is streaming audio. I am checking if the stream is up by making a HTTP connection, checking the request code and reading up to 100 bytes.

This is what I have so far:

```
val url = new URL(streamUrl)
val con = url.openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
con.getReponseCode match {
  case 200 => {
    readBytes(streamUrl)
  }
  case _ => Option(false)
}
```

If the http response code is 200 then I read the bytes. How can I read the first N bytes of `streamUrl`?

Comment: and... what's the question?

Comment: Added the question

Comment: From where you are reading the file? Are you using Play, Akka or other framework?

Comment: Call `getInputStream` then use @marcospereira's linked question